# Move all JPGs and rename them into one directory

Tags: command-line, mv, cp

.Hi.
I have a bunch of jpgs in 100s of subfolders , I know I can move them all with this command

```
find -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec mv -av {} /home/root/private/pics/ \;
```

But my all my jpgs are like this in each subfolder

```
0001.jpg  
0002.jpg  
0003.jpg  
0004.jpg  
0005.jpg
```

and so up to 2500.jpgs in one folder

So it overwrites them when putting them into the directory 'pics' because most of them have the same file name

How can i rename or avoid the same JPG image names being overwrited with this command?

```
find -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec mv -av {} /home/root/private/pics/ \;
```

Comment: drop the -a please.

Comment: Why do you want all files in one single directory? I have a lot of pictures too, and I store them in a directory tree with sub-directory paths .../year/month/day for example .../2021/07/20. Several tools can easily manage the pictures in such a directory tree. It works well also with some other directory tree, probably also what you have (or had).

Answer (score 3):

Use the `numbered` when using `mv`

```
numbered, t
make numbered backups
```

[man mv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)

`mv --backup=TYPE` with type being 1 of these:

- none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
- numbered, t     make numbered backups
- existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
- simple, never   always make simple backups

Comment: Very new to linux should the command look like this: find -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec mv -av {} /home/root/private/pics/ \;  numbered, t ?

Comment: Getting this error: find -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec mv numbered, t -av {} /home/root/private/imgs/ \; ERROR :: Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mv: invalid option -- 'a'

Comment: it is `mv --backup=numbered` ;-)

Comment: find -type f -iname "*.jpg" -exec mv -av --backup=numbered {} /home/user/private/imgs/ \;  still giving me same error :mv: invalid option -- 'a'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: @1014Noob `mv` doesn't have a `-a` option.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Thunar package manager, to rename and relocate files in bulk. You can install it with this command: `sudo apt-get install -y thunar`

Comment: Let me know if this helps.